How to configure a global size for all Seaborn figure-level plots?
I'm trying to pre-configure a global size for all Seaborn figure-level plots (i.e. relplot, displot, catplot), without manually specifying the size every time I call them.
I can do the same for axes-level ones using sns.set_theme(rc={'figure.figsize': (12, 6)}). All axes-level plots after that line have my configured size, no need to specify again. However, so far I could only set the same size for each figure-level plot  using height and aspect arguments like sns.catplot(..., height=6, aspect=2) -- which is tedious. Another option I have tried is using Figure.set_figwidth() with Figure.set_figheight() and it resulted in even more lines of code.
I wonder if there's a way to pre-configure the size for all Seaborn figure-level plots?
